# correct the definition: Binary operations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm supposed to correct the italicized word

1) A binary operation * is *commutative* if and only if a * b=b * a

it is the definition of commutative though

2) A binary operation * on a set S is *associative* iff for all $a,b,c \in S$

we have (b * c) * a = b * (c * a)

that is associative, not sure what to change it to

3) A subset H of a set S is *closed* under a binary operation * on S if $a * b \in H$ for all $a,b \in S$

shouldn't $a,b \in H$ and $a * b \in H$ in order for it to be closed?

Comment: yes, it should be for all $a,b\in H$

Comment: im going to say 1,2 are correct and that in 3 that *closed* should be changed to *not closed* and give the reasoning?

Comment: sounds good, also in $1$ they do not say for all $a,b\in S$. Although I personally would not mind.

Comment: yeah I noticed that as well, seemed odd without it

Comment: The subset in 3) _is_ closed under $*$. I think the statement as it stands is true if we take it merely as a logical statement, not as a definition. It is not the _definition_ of "closed" (because for a definition, there is an implicit "and only if", and the corresponding statement with "if and only if" instead of "if" is false).